# WordPress - Session values changes from page to page

Tags: php, wordpress, session, plugins, shortcode

`functions.php`

```
<?php
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') ){ die(); }

ob_start();
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
```

`plugins/bestellung/bestellung.php`

```
<?php
add_shortcode('disp_bestellung_sidebar', 'display_side');
function display_side() {
    if($_SESSION["ptitle"] != "") {
        echo '<h3 class="bestellung_sidebar_title">Product</h3>';
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

`plugins/bestellung/bridge.php`

```
if (isset($_POST['prtitle'])) {
    $_SESSION["ptitle"] = $_POST['prtitle'];
}
header( 'Location: /bestellung/' );
```

Here in `bridge.php` I can get $_SESSION["ptitle"] with its value.
But after it redirects to another page i.e. '/bestellung/' there are other keys/values that had been set before this.

Why the values inside the session changed to something else?

Answer (score 0):

You should check on each page to see if the session has started at first:

```
if( ! session_id() ) {
    session_start();
}

if ( isset( $_POST['prtitle'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION["ptitle"] = $_POST['prtitle'];
}

wp_safe_redirect( home_url() . '/bestellung/' );
exit;
......

add_shortcode( 'disp_bestellung_sidebar', 'display_side' );
function display_side() {

    if( ! session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }

    if( isset( $_SESSION["ptitle"] ) &&  $_SESSION["ptitle"] != "" ) {
        echo '<h3 class="bestellung_sidebar_title">Product</h3>';
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had set it but it didn't work. I have set it in `wp-config`, in `functions`, and in each separate file. No luck.

Comment: Probably a problem with redirects. Why not use the WordPress redirect function? Please check [wp_safe_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/)